# Using algorithm2e with polyglossia produces undesired emphasized text

Tags: xetex, algorithm2e, polyglossia, cyrillic, emphasis

Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfonttt}{CMU Typewriter Text}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
% \setmainlanguage{ukrainian}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \SetKwData{Left}{left}
    \SetKwData{Right}{right}
    \SetKwFunction{Swap}{Swap}

    \For{$i \leftarrow 0$ \KwTo $n$}{
        \If{$\Left_i > 0$ {\bf and} $\Right_i > 0$}{
            \Swap{$\Left_i$, $\Right_i$}\;
        }
    }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

This code produces the following output:

[image: Desired output.]

Now, if I uncomment the `\setmainlanguage{ukrainian}` line, the output changes slightly:

[image: Output with undesired emphasis.]

As you see, here the keywords `to`, `and`, and arguments `left` and `right` became emphasized. It's not really that big of a problem, but it still bothers me, italic font here seems out of place. The same result occurs for Russian and Bulgarian, e.g. languages with Cyrillic script. What could be causing this behavior? I'd be really grateful for any advice.

Comment: Try adding `\renewcommand{\ArgSty}[1]{\textnormal{\upshape #1}\unskip}` to your preamble after loading [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e). I'm not sure what else this might mess up...

Comment: @Werner Thank you, that works. Turns out `algorithm2e` even has a predefined macro `\SetArgSty` for that which is set by default to `emph`. But then, why the arguments are upright with English? I'm confused.

Comment: With an up-to-date MiKTeX distribution, it seems the problem has now disappeared. Can you test this ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is very old and the problem cannot be reproduced on an up-to-date MiKTeX distribution